# Load media manager in frontend with October CMS

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to open the media manager in frontend, in a modal, when you click on a button.

Basically, the same behavior than when you click on a mediafinder form widget in backend, but in frontend.

Is it possible ?

Thank you

The idea behind that is to allow end user to choose and change images directly from frontend. I'm planning to extend the Content Editor plugin to integrate media manager when you click on the image to pick an image from the media manager instead of uploading a new one each time.